# Yii: Unable to load the url page " Error 404 Unable to resolve the request "user/userpage"."

Tags: php, yii

I am a yiibie, i am trying to get user data from the user table against there id.  For that I have made a `userpage.php` file in the views and also written a function in the `user controller` named `Userpage` to get the user data from the table. After doing all this when I write the url `"localhost/projectname/user/userpage?id="anyid"` it gives me an error

```
Error 404
Unable to resolve the request "user/userpage".
```

here is the code for my `UserController`

```
<?php

class UserController extends RController
{
    /**
    * @var string the default layout for the views. Defaults to '//layouts/column2', meaning
    * using two-column layout. See 'protected/views/layouts/column2.php'.
    */
    public $layout='//layouts/admin';

    /**
    * @return array action filters
    */
    public function filters()
    {
        return array(
            //          'accessControl', // perform access control for CRUD operations
            //          'postOnly + delete', // we only allow deletion via POST request
                    'rights',
        );
    }

    /**
    * Specifies the access control rules.
    * This method is used by the 'accessControl' filter.
    * @return array access control rules
    */
    public function accessRules()
    {
        return array(
            array('allow',  // allow all users to perform 'index' and 'view' actions
                'actions'=>array('index','view'),
                'users'=>array('*'),
            ),
            array('allow', // allow authenticated user to perform 'create' and 'update' actions
                'actions'=>array('create','update'),
                'users'=>array('@'),
            ),
            array('allow', // allow admin user to perform 'admin' and 'delete' actions
                'actions'=>array('admin','delete'),
                'users'=>array('admin'),
            ),
            array('deny',  // deny all users
                'users'=>array('*'),
            ),
        );
    }

    /**
    * Displays a particular model.
    * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be displayed
    */
    public function actionView($id)
    {
        $this->render('view',array(
            'model'=>$this->loadModel($id),
        ));
    }
        public function actionUserpage($id)
        {
            $this->layout='main';
        $this->render('userpage',array(
            'model'=>$this->loadModel($id),
        ));
        }

    /**
    * Creates a new model.
    * If creation is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
    */
    public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model=new User;

        // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
        // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

        if(isset($_POST['User']))
        {
                    $rnd = rand(0,9999);  // generate random number between 0-9999
            $model->attributes=$_POST['User'];
                        $uploadedFile=CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'image');
            $fileName = "{$rnd}-{$uploadedFile}";  // random number + file name
            $model->image = $fileName;
            if($model->save())
                            {
                $uploadedFile->saveAs(Yii::app()->basePath.'/'.$fileName);  // image will uplode to rootDirectory/event/
                $this->redirect(array('admin'));
            }
                $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
        }

        $this->render('create',array(
        'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }

    /**
    * Updates a particular model.
    * If update is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
    * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be updated
    */
    public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model=$this->loadModel($id);

        // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
        // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

        if(isset($_POST['User']))
        {
                    $_POST['User']['image'] = $model->image;
            $model->attributes=$_POST['User'];
                        $uploadedFile=CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'image');
            if($model->save())
                             {
                if(!empty($uploadedFile))  // check if uploaded file is set or not
                {
                 $uploadedFile->saveAs(Yii::app()->basePath.'/'.$model->image);
                }
                $this->redirect(array('admin'));
            }
                $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
        }

        $this->render('update',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }

    /**
    * Deletes a particular model.
    * If deletion is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'admin' page.
    * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be deleted
    */
    public function actionDelete($id)
    {
        if(Yii::app()->request->isPostRequest)
        {
            // we only allow deletion via POST request
            $this->loadModel($id)->delete();

            // if AJAX request (triggered by deletion via admin grid view), we should not redirect the browser
            if(!isset($_GET['ajax']))
                $this->redirect(isset($_POST['returnUrl']) ? $_POST['returnUrl'] : array('admin'));
        }
        else
            throw new CHttpException(400,'Invalid request. Please do not repeat this request again.');
    }

    /**
    * Lists all models.
    */
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('User');
        $this->render('index',array(
            'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
        ));
    }

    /**
    * Manages all models.
    */
    public function actionAdmin()
    {
        $model=new User('search');
        $model->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values
        if(isset($_GET['User']))
            $model->attributes=$_GET['User'];

        $this->render('admin',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }

    /**
    * Returns the data model based on the primary key given in the GET variable.
    * If the data model is not found, an HTTP exception will be raised.
    * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be loaded
    * @return User the loaded model
    * @throws CHttpException
    */
    public function loadModel($id)
    {
        $model=User::model()->findByPk($id);
        if($model===null)
            throw new CHttpException(404,'The requested page does not exist.');
        return $model;
    }

    /**
    * Performs the AJAX validation.
    * @param User $model the model to be validated
    */
    protected function performAjaxValidation($model)
    {
        if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==='user-form')
        {
            echo CActiveForm::validate($model);
            Yii::app()->end();
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the code for my view file(userpage.php)

```
 <div class="profile">
 <div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-4">
 <img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseurl;?>/img/<?php echo $model->profile->picture;?>" class="img-responsive"><br>
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-6">
 <h2 class="profile-name"><?php echo $model->username;?></h2>
 <hYii: Unable to load the url page " Error 404 Unable to resolve the request "user/userpage"."
```

And this is the config/main.php

```
<?php

// uncomment the following to define a path alias
// Yii::setPathOfAlias('local','path/to/local-folder');

// This is the main Web application configuration. Any writable
// CWebApplication properties can be configured here.

return array(
     'theme' => 'bootstrap',
    'basePath'=>dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'..',
    'name'=>'emergency response system',

    // preloading 'log' component
    'preload'=>array('log'),
'aliases' => array(
        'bootstrap' => 'ext.bootstrap'),
    // autoloading model and component classes
    'import'=>array(
        'application.models.*',
        'application.components.*',
         'bootstrap.behaviors.*',
                'bootstrap.helpers.*',
                'bootstrap.widgets.*',
                'application.modules.user.models.*',
                'application.modules.user.components.*',
                'application.modules.rights.*',
                'application.modules.rights.components.*',
                'application.extensions.EAjaxUpload.*',//for multiuploadfiles
            'application.extensions.kml.*'
            ),

    'modules'=>array(
        // uncomment the following to enable the Gii tool

        'gii'=>array(
            'class'=>'system.gii.GiiModule',
            'password'=>'ers',
                     'generatorPaths' => array(
                'bootstrap.gii', ),
            // If removed, Gii defaults to localhost only. Edit carefully to taste.
            'ipFilters'=>array('127.0.0.1','::1'),
        ),
            'user' => array(
            'tableUsers' => 'user',
            'tableProfiles' => 'profiles',
            'tableProfileFields' => 'profiles_fields',
//                # encrypting method (php hash function)
//                'hash' => 'md5',
// 
//                # send activation email
//                'sendActivationMail' => true,
// 
//                # allow access for non-activated users
//                'loginNotActiv' => false,
// 
//                # activate user on registration (only sendActivationMail = false)
//                'activeAfterRegister' => false,
// 
//                # automatically login from registration
//                'autoLogin' => true,
// 
//                # registration path
//               'registrationUrl' => array('/user/registration'),
//
//                # recovery password path
//                'recoveryUrl' => array('/user/recovery'),
// 
//                # login form path
//                'loginUrl' => array('/user/login'),
// 
//                # page after login
//                'returnUrl' => array('/user/profile'),
// 
//               # page after logout
//               'returnLogoutUrl' => array('/user/login'),


    ),
             'rights'=>array(
             'install'=>true,
//                 'superuserName'=>'Admin', // Name of the role with super user privileges. 
//               'authenticatedName'=>'Authenticated',  // Name of the authenticated user role. 
//               'userIdColumn'=>'id', // Name of the user id column in the database. 
//               'userNameColumn'=>'username',  // Name of the user name column in the database. 
//               'enableBizRule'=>true,  // Whether to enable authorization item business rules. 
//               'enableBizRuleData'=>true,   // Whether to enable data for business rules. 
//               'displayDescription'=>true,  // Whether to use item description instead of name. 
//               'flashSuccessKey'=>'RightsSuccess', // Key to use for setting success flash messages. 
//               'flashErrorKey'=>'RightsError', // Key to use for setting error flash messages. 
//               'baseUrl'=>'/rights', // Base URL for Rights. Change if module is nested. 
//               'layout'=>'rights.views.layouts.main',  // Layout to use for displaying Rights. 
//               'appLayout'=>'application.views.layouts.main', // Application layout. 
//               'cssFile'=>'rights.css', // Style sheet file to use for Rights. 
//               'install'=>false,  // Whether to enable installer. 
//               'debug'=>false, 
        ),
            ),

    // application components
    'components'=>array(

        'user'=>array(
                    'class'=>'RWebUser',
            // enable cookie-based authentication
            'allowAutoLogin'=>true,
                    'loginUrl'=>array('/user/login'),
        ),
            'authManager'=>array(
                'class'=>'RDbAuthManager',
                'connectionID'=>'db',
                'defaultRoles'=>array('Authenticated', 'Guest'),

//                'itemTable'=>'authitem',
//                'itemChildTable'=>'authitemchild',
//                'assignmentTable'=>'authassignment',
//                'rightsTable'=>'rights',
        ),


        'bootstrap' => array(
            'class' => 'bootstrap.components.BsApi',),

        // uncomment the following to enable URLs in path-format

        'urlManager'=>array(
            'urlFormat'=>'path',
                     'showScriptName'=>false,
            'rules'=>array(
        //'<controller:\w+>'=>'<controller>/list',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>/<title>'=>'<controller>/view',
                '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
            ),
        ),


        // database settings are configured in database.php
        //'db'=>require(dirname(__FILE__).'/database.php'),

        'db'=>array(
            'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=response_system',
            'emulatePrepare' => true,
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => '',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
        ),

        'errorHandler'=>array(
            // use 'site/error' action to display errors
            'errorAction'=>'site/error',
        ),

        'log'=>array(
            'class'=>'CLogRouter',
            'routes'=>array(
                array(
                    'class'=>'CFileLogRoute',
                    'levels'=>'error, warning',
                ),
                // uncomment the following to show log messages on web pages

                array(
                    'class'=>'CWebLogRoute',
                ),

            ),
        ),

    ),

    // application-level parameters that can be accessed
    // using Yii::app()->params['paramName']
    'params'=>array(
        // this is used in contact page
        'adminEmail'=>'webmaster@example.com',
    ),

);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check you have a proper view named

```
 userpage.php
```

in the  view directory for user 
(the related view directory for user depend of the user component you use.)

check the namespace or the config/main.php of your app for find the right dir.

Check also if you have properly assigned userpage in the accessRules of your User model.

And be absoluty sure you are using a valid $id value.  because if the value of id is not found in db should raise this kind of message

and try adding prettyUrl = true  otherwise you can't use your notation

```
     'urlManager'=>array(
        'urlFormat'=>'path',
        'showScriptName'=>false,
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,   // Disable r= routes
        'rules'=>array(
    //'<controller:\w+>'=>'<controller>/list',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>/<title>'=>'<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
        ),
    ),
```

Comment: properly assigned userpage in the accessRules of your User model or the Usercontroller..?

Comment: I'sorry , in the controller, the accessRules are in controller, check you have the entry 'userpage' in correct array. for testing I suggest you  insert the entry in a no restiction entry (*) so you don't to worry about authentication..

Comment: I have tried all these things but i dont why nothing is happening, i have updated the question with my main..php file, please have a look at it.

Comment: You use RWebUser component where are placed the related view ? show me also the namescape of the controller ..

Comment: Just a simple question. what's happen when you instead of localhost/projectname/user/userpage?id="anyid"   call localhost/projectname/user/view?id="anyid" ... All work right?

Comment: no it gives an error 
Error 404
Unable to resolve the request "user/view"

Comment: When all the call you do to the user controller give you this error, please comfirm...

Comment: yes all the calls to the user controller gives an error, i think you know what the problem is

Comment: Also  if you simply call the index this way localhost/projectname/user .. please confirm

Comment: no upon this it gives me the list of registered users

Comment: well the index work.. well, I'sorry but i'm tired i need a rest we can continue tomorrow? in the afternoon i comment if you not already solved

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97084/discussion-between-salik-asad-and-scaisedge).

Comment: I have update the answer please do this check also and comment me the result. i see it tomorrow

Comment: I have update the answer.. But Remeber very well Respect please.

Comment: sorry have i said anything wrong, i didn't understand your last comment, sorry if you have found anything wrong.

Answer (score 0):

you need to also register your `userpage` action in your `public function accessRules()` function , without it you can not access this action from a url.

```
public function accessRules()
    {
        return array(
            array('allow',  // allow all users to perform 'index' and 'view' actions
                'actions'=>array('index','view'),
                'users'=>array('*'),
            ),
            array('allow', // allow authenticated user to perform 'create' and 'update' actions
                'actions'=>array('create','update','userpage'),
                'users'=>array('@'),
            ),
            array('allow', // allow admin user to perform 'admin' and 'delete' actions
                'actions'=>array('admin','delete'),
                'users'=>array('admin'),
            ),
            array('deny',  // deny all users
                'users'=>array('*'),
            ),
        );
    }
```

Please note, the above change will let only users to use the `userpage` action, if you want it to be public add it to `'users'=>array('*'),` array

Comment: How to do that, can you please update the above code. Thankyou

Comment: this didn't worked out, still gives the same error, i copied the whole thing in the access rules. Please see if there is any other problem.

Comment: when you access the url, are you logged in o not ?

Comment: Yes i am logged in..!!

Comment: I think it is an issue with your project folder name in url,  try changing setting s in config/routes.php like $config['base_url'] = "http://somesite.com/somedir/";

Comment: No @scaisEdge i haven't, do you have a sloutin for this..??