# yii2 does not load the views yii\web\HttpException:404

Tags: yii2

I am new to yii2 and I cannot find a solution please help mi
controller

```
class ReporteController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
            ],
            'rules' => [
                    
                    [
                        'actions' => ['estudiantes'],
                        'allow' => true,
                        'roles' => ['@'],
                    ],
                ],
        ];
    }

   
    public function actionEstudiantes()
    {
        
        
        $user_id = Yii::$app->user->identity->id;
        //echo $user_id;
        $userdistrito = \common\models\UserDistrito::find()->where(['user_id'=>$user_id])->one();
        
        if (empty($userdistrito)) {
            $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
                         'query' => Estudiante::find() 
            ]); 
        }else{
            $dist = $userdistrito->distrito_id; 
            $condition = "instructorbiblico_id in (SELECT id FROM instructorbiblico where iglesia_id in (SELECT id FROM iglesia WHERE distrito_id = $dist))"; 
            $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
                             'query' => Estudiante::find()->where($condition),
            ]);     
        }
        return $this->render('estudiantes', [
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]);
    }
```

...

views in backend\views\reporte

estudiantes.php

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use kartik\export\ExportMenu;
use kartik\grid\GridView;
/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $searchModel app\models\EstudianteSearch */
/* @var $dataProvider yii\data\ActiveDataProvider */

$this->title = Yii::t('app', 'Estudiantes');
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<div class="estudiante-index">

  

</div>
<div>
  <?php
$gridColumns = [
    ['class' => 'kartik\grid\SerialColumn'],
    //'id',
    //'nombres',
    [
                    'attribute' => 'iglesia',
                    'label' => 'Iglesia',
                    'value' => 'instructorbiblico.unidadaccion.iglesia.nombre',
            ], 
            //'iglesia.nombre',
            [
                    'attribute' => 'unidadaccion',
                    'label' => 'Unidad Accion',
                    'value' => 'instructorbiblico.unidadaccion.nombre',
            ], 
            [
                    'attribute' => 'Instructor ',
                    'label' => 'Instructor',
                    'value' =>'instructorbiblico.nombre',  
            ], 
            
             
            'nombres',
            'celular',
            'edad',
            [
                'attribute' => 'sexo',
                'label' => 'sexo',
                'value' => function($model){ 
                    if ($model->sexo == 0){
                        return 'M';
                    }
                    if ($model->sexo == 1){
                        return 'F';
                    }
                    else {
                        return '';
                    }
                },
            ], 
            [
                'attribute' => 'estado',
                'label' => 'Estado',
                'value' => function($model){ 
                    if ($model->estado == 0){
                        return 'Inactivo';
                    }
                    if ($model->estado == 1){
                        return 'Activo';
                    }
                    else {
                        return '';
                    }
                },
            ], 
    
 
];
  ?>  
    
    
</div>
<div>
    
<?php

echo ExportMenu::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns' => $gridColumns,
    'exportConfig' => [
        ExportMenu::FORMAT_TEXT => false,
        ExportMenu::FORMAT_HTML => false,
        ExportMenu::FORMAT_EXCEL => false,
        ExportMenu::FORMAT_PDF => [
            'pdfConfig' => [
                'methods' => [
                    'SetTitle' => 'Grid Export - Krajee.com',
                    'SetSubject' => 'Generating PDF files via yii2-export extension has never been easy',
                    'SetHeader' => ['Krajee Library Export||Generated On: ' . date("r")],
                    'SetFooter' => ['|Page {PAGENO}|'],
                    'SetAuthor' => 'Kartik Visweswaran',
                    'SetCreator' => 'Kartik Visweswaran',
                    'SetKeywords' => 'Krajee, Yii2, Export, PDF, MPDF, Output, GridView, Grid, yii2-grid, yii2-mpdf, yii2-export',
                ]
            ]
        ],
    ],
    'dropdownOptions' => [
        'label' => 'Export All',
        'class' => 'btn btn-outline-secondary'
    ]
]) . "<hr>\n".
GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns' => $gridColumns,
]);
?>
</div>
```

1 error

yii\web\HttpException:404   exception 'yii\base\InvalidRouteException' with message 'Unable to resolve the request "reporte/estudiantes".' in /home/sebdcom/public_html/proy/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php:537
Stack trace:
#0 /home/sebdcom/public_html/proy/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Application.php(103): yii\base\Module->runAction('reporte/estudia...', Array)
#1 /home/sebdcom/public_html/proy/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(386): yii\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(yii\web\Request))
#2 /home/sebdcom/public_html/proy/backend/web/index.php(17): yii\base\Application->run()
#3 {main}

Next exception 'yii\web\NotFoundHttpException' with message 'Página no encontrada.' in /home/sebdcom/public_html/proy/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Application.php:115
Stack trace:
#0 /home/sebdcom/public_html/proy/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(386): yii\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(yii\web\Request))
#1 /home/sebdcom/public_html/proy/backend/web/index.php(17): yii\base\Application->run()
#2 {main}

2 error

yii\web\HttpException:404   exception 'yii\base\InvalidRouteException' with message 'Unable to resolve the request "css/Bootstrap.min.css".' in /home/sebdcom/public_html/proy/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php:537
Stack trace:
#0 /home/sebdcom/public_html/proy/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Application.php(103): yii\base\Module->runAction('css/Bootstrap.m...', Array)
#1 /home/sebdcom/public_html/proy/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(386): yii\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(yii\web\Request))
#2 /home/sebdcom/public_html/proy/backend/web/index.php(17): yii\base\Application->run()
#3 {main}

Next exception 'yii\web\NotFoundHttpException' with message 'Página no encontrada.' in /home/sebdcom/public_html/proy/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Application.php:115
Stack trace:
#0 /home/sebdcom/public_html/proy/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(386): yii\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(yii\web\Request))
#1 /home/sebdcom/public_html/proy/backend/web/index.php(17): yii\base\Application->run()
#2 {main}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Yii: Unable to load the url page " Error 404 Unable to resolve the request "user/userpage"."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34103085/yii-unable-to-load-the-url-page-error-404-unable-to-resolve-the-request-user)

Comment: Please show us configuration for UrlManager for backend.

Comment: First stop using Kartik or any other extension. Use only if you have no other option. Kartik doesn't under the real world problems. What is the code class ReporteController extends Controller before this and is this estudiantes.php file exists?

Comment: Are you (as the user) logged in? Because your `behaviors` allow to enter the `actionEstudiantes` just to logged users.